# Reference Request: Circuit Complexity Theory Course

Tags: reference-request, circuit-complexity

I want to learn circuit complexity theory. I have found this book "Introduction to Circuit Complexity
A Uniform Approach" by Heribert Vollmer. I have also found lecture notes of one course
[Circuit Complexity Course by Sam Buss](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esbuss/CourseWeb/Math262A_2013F/)

But i want to listen to lecture videos along with reading book. Can you recommend any such course.

Comment: Not a video course, but I warmly recommend the comprehensive and well explained book by Stasys Jukna. It is thicker and newer than Vollmer's book. https://web.vu.lt/mif/s.jukna/boolean/index.html